# Execute() statement in the if else doesnt work , PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

i want to check if item named 'BUC test' is already in the database or not, but suddenly my `$stmt->execute();` is not working

```
$cek_name=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT name FROM equipment WHERE id='$_GET[bie]' and name='BUC test'"));
    if ($cek_name > 0)
    {
      $duplicate = "Equipment Name is already in use.";
    }
    else
    {
      echo 'this will execute';
      $stmt1->bind_param('ssssss',$id,$type, $name, $qty, $usd, $idr);
      $stmt1->execute();
    }
$type = 'BUC';
  $name = 'BUC test';
  $qty = '1';
  $usd = '0';
  $idr = '0';
  $id= $_GET['bie'];
```

if i put the `$stmt->execute();` outside if else its work, does anyone have a clue?
fyi : `echo 'this will execute';` is displayed.

please help! thanks!

Comment: You cannot use `mysql_` and `mysqli_` API's interchangably. Stick to `mysqli`

Comment: which one is mysqli_ API? @RiggsFolly

Comment: How did you connect to the database? Did you use `mysql_connect()` or `mysqli_connect()`

Comment: @RiggsFolly $connection = mysql_connect($host, $user_db, $pass_db);

Comment: Then you cannot just magically start using `$stmt1->bind_param()` which is `mysqli_` API code, anyway, you dont prepare a query to generate a valid `$stmt` anyway

Comment: @RiggsFolly oh , i see.. so i should change it to mysqli? query already exist and prepared, i just dont show it

Comment: and also if i put execute it in the outside of if esle , bind param and execute works..

Comment: Then I cannot help as you do not show us enough of your code and we try not to make guesses

Comment: $stmt1 = $mysqli -> prepare ("INSERT INTO bom_equipment(id,type, name, qty, usd, idr) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)"); @RiggsFolly

Comment: there is my prepare query @RiggsFolly